# "Float up left"? Make divs start at the top of container and grow down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a larger div with smaller divs in it. This is how it currently look:
[image]

However, I want it to look like this:
[image]
Basically, I want all the divs inside the "div-container" to float up and left as opposed to left and down. Perhaps float is not the thing I am looking for. How should I go about this issue?

Here you can see for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastian3495/ea6L08bu/9/

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="background: yellow;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 200px;background: brown;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background: green;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background: purple;"></div>

</div>
```

css

```
.container {
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You did not post the actual HTML and CSS.

Comment: Well `float: left` would not align the boxes at the bottom of the container, so *something* unusual is going on.

Comment: If you're using `display: inline-block;` then you need to add `vertical-align: top;`

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that's it! Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend you to read about the flex box, it's a better solution for what you are trying to do, and your layout it's even one of the examples here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @sebastiannielsen, floating model doesn't give 'up-down' float feature. You may want use flex-model, using `display:flex` in the container.

Comment: You should be able to use `.container { display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-start` } to do what you're asking. (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Ah, I see arieljuod beat me to it :)

Comment: I am well aware of flex, I don't use it for a specific reason and it's not that I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `inline-block` then you just need to use `vertical-align:top`

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="background: yellow;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="height: 200px;background: brown;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background: green;"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background: purple;"></div>

</div>
```